# Bloating a cylinder

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

So I have a cylinder that I have extruded some other geometry onto. I need a way to bloat the vertical lines of the original geometry. Thanks guys!

I need to turn this:

```
/ \
|||
```

Into this:

```
 / \
( | )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is by using *[Proportional Editing](http://blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/transformations/transform_control/proportional_edit.html)* (<kbd>O</kbd>):

1. Add extra geometry to deform by adding some *loop cuts* (<kbd>⎈ 
   Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>)
2. Enable *proportional editing* (<kbd>O</kbd>)
3. Select a falloff in *3D view > Header*. I used the default, *Smooth*, but you might want to try some other ones and see what you like best. Note that you can change the falloff in the *Redo panel* (<kbd>F6</kbd>) after scaling in step 4.
4. Select the center loop cut and scale with <kbd>S</kbd>. Use <kbd>[image: MW] MW</kbd> to adjust the distance at which proportional editing will affect other vertices.

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the graphic, it was super helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For a quick modeling, I'll suggest to use the "Cast" modifier, with Shpere cast type selected.

[image]

Comment: but you have to limit the effect with a vertex group to keep the roof's shape.

Comment: Yeah, that's right! I thougth the roof was a separate object to be put above.